# Active Directory Administrative Center Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Natively Active Directory Administrative Center (ADAC) doesn't give you the powershell alternative when performing any function, like Exchange Management Console. Is there a way to change this or is there an addin that will show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear MS offered this option in the current rev.  No mention of it in [their docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560651%28WS.10%29.aspx) that I can see.  Looks as if it is not possible to extend either. Funny, because [they claim](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2009/03/27/active-directory-administrative-center-for-windows-server-2008-r2-implemented-using-adpowershell.aspx) it was all written in Powershell.  Too bad.

Comment: and from what I have gathered from conversations with MSoft reps ADAC is using Powershell to do everything.